# Typescript "static imports"?

Tags: typescript

I remember from some language the concept of 'static imports', where you could import a whole library into a module and use the classes in there without having to use a qualifier, but the names were made present at the top level of the module. I.e. if I write a max function and a min function in my included utility.ts library, I'd just like to write `min(1,2)` rather than `util.min(1,2)`I realize I could import each function by name to achieve that, but would rather avoid doing this for 30 different functions and utility classes inside each module that uses them.

Would also not want to clutter up the global namespace is there some way to do this with an import of some kind?

Comment: Luckily, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Use import { min, max } from './util' or if the methods are defined as static simply import the file and use: Util.min()